# What happens when I pass a boolean dataframe to the indexing operator for another dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There's something fundamental about manipulating pandas dataframes which I am not getting.

**TL,DR**: passing a boolean series to the indexing operator [] of a pandas dataframe returns the rows or columns of that df where the series was True. But passing a boolean *dataframe* (ie: multidimensional) returns a weird dataframe consisting only of NaN values.

Edit: to rephrase: why is it possible to pass a dataframe of boolean values to another dataframe, and what does it do? With a series, this makes sense, but with a dataframe, I don't understand what's happening 'under the hood', and why in my example I get a dataframe of null NaN values.

**In detail with examples:**

When I pass a pandas boolean Series to the indexing operator, it returns a list of rows corresponding to indices where the Series is True:

```
test_list = [[1,2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5]]
test_df = pd.DataFrame(test_list)
test_df

    0   1   2   3
0   1   2   3.0 4.0
1   3   4   5.0 NaN
2   4   5   NaN NaN

test_df[test_df[2].isnull()]

    0   1   2   3
2   4   5   NaN NaN
```

So far, so good. But what happens when I do this:

```
test_df[test_df.isnull()]


0   1   2   3
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Why does this return a dataframe consisting of only NaN values? I would expect it to either return an error, or perhaps to return a new dataframe truncated using the boolean mask dataframe. But I find this output completely confusing.

Edit: As an outcome I would expect to get an error. I don't understand why it's possible to pass a dataframe under these circumstances, or why it returns this dataframe of NaN values

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html

Comment: Does `test_df.isna()` return the desired result?

Comment: Post an expected outcome.

Comment: I believe (but please wait for an answer of a more experienced user or LoukasPap) that it's precisely because you pass an entire df that it returns only NaN. Usually you filter out (or transform) these NaN values as I developed in my answer. The error 'message' is precisely that all the returned values are NaN, including those that were not NaN, thereby allowing us to see  that something wrong happened. No? Also edited my answer on how to count NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test_df[..]` calls an indexing method [`__getitem__()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L2987-L3047). From the source code:

```py
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        ...

        # Do we have a (boolean) DataFrame?
        if isinstance(key, DataFrame):
            return self.where(key)

        # Do we have a (boolean) 1d indexer?
        if com.is_bool_indexer(key):
            return self._getitem_bool_array(key)
```

As you can see, if the `key` is a boolean DataFrame, it will call [pandas.DataFrame.where()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html). The function of `where()` is to replace values where the condition is `False` with `NaN` by default.

```
# print(test_df.isnull())
       0      1      2      3
0  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False   True
2  False  False   True   True

# print(test_df)
    0   1   2   3
0   1   2   3.0 4.0
1   3   4   5.0 NaN
2   4   5   NaN NaN
```

`test_df.where(test_df.isnull())` replaces not null values with `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all values are transformed to NaN because you passed the entire df. The error 'message', precisely, is that all the returned values are NaN (including those that were not NaN), which allows us to see that something wrong happened. But surely a more experienced user will be able to answer you in more detail. Also note most of the time you want to remove or transform these NaN--not just flag them.

Following my comment above and LoukasPap's answer, here is a way to flag, count, and then remove or transform these NaN values:

First flag NaN values:

```
test_df.isnull()
```

You might also be interested to count your NaN values:

```
test_df.isnull().sum() # sum NaN by column
test_df.isnull().sum().sum() # get grand total of NaN
```

You can now drop NaN values by row

```
test_df.dropna()
```

Or by column:

```
test_df.dropna(axis=1)
```

Or replace NaN values by median:

```
test_df.fillna(test_df.median())
```

Comment: Louis want to know why it does not throw an error, or why does it show a dataframe full of NaN.